# Why I have got this error "Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workService' "?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nested

Stuff.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUFF")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Stuff {
}
```

Work.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORK")
public class Work extends Stuff{
}
```

AbstractDao:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {
private final Class<T> persistentClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractDao(){
    this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getByKey(PK key) {
    return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
}

public void persist(T entity) {
    getSession().persist(entity);
}

public void update(T entity) {
    getSession().update(entity);
}

public void delete(T entity) {
    getSession().delete(entity);
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
    return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
}
}
```

StuffDao:

```
public interface StuffDao<T> {
}
```

StuffDaoImpl:

```
@Repository("stuffDao")
public class StuffDaoImpl<T> extends AbstractDao<Integer,T> implements     StuffDao<T> {


private Class<T> persistenceClass;
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
public StuffDaoImpl(final Class<T> persistenceClass){
    this.persistenceClass = persistenceClass;
}

public final EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public final void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager){
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

private Class<T> type;

public StuffDaoImpl() {
    Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
    type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
}
```

WorkDao which is inhetitence from StuffDao:

```
public interface WorkDao extends StuffDao<Work>{
}
```

WorkDaoImpl:

```
@Repository("workDao")
public class WorkDaoImpl extends StuffDaoImpl<Work> implements WorkDao {


public WorkDaoImpl(){
    super();
}

}
```

StuffService:

```
public interface StuffService<T> {
}
```

StuffServiceImpl:

```
 @Service("stuffService")
@Transactional
public class StuffServiceImpl<T> implements StuffService<T> {

@Autowired
private StuffDao<T> dao;
}
```

WorkService:

```
public interface WorkService extends StuffService<Work>{
}
```

WorkServiceImpl:

```
@Service("workService")
@Transactional
public class WorkServiceImpl extends StuffServiceImpl<Work> implements   WorkService {

@Autowired
private WorkDao daow;
}
```

hibernate-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

<context:component-scan  base-package="com.newbaz" />
<!--<context:annotation-config />-->
<!--<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>-->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.newbaz.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

        </props>
    </property>

</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">

    <property name="converters">
        <util:list>
            <bean id="roleToUserProfile" class="com.newbaz.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter" />
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>


<!--<bean id="productDao" class="com.newbaz.dao.ProductDao" />-->
</beans>
```

And finally Error:

```
[ERROR] Nested in    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.newbaz.dao.StuffDao com.newbaz.service.StuffServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workDao' defined in file [/home/dorsa/IdeaProjects/spring/newbazzar/target/classes/com/newbaz/dao/WorkDaoImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.newbaz.dao.WorkDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.newbaz.dao.AbstractDao.<init>(AbstractDao.java:19)
at com.newbaz.dao.StuffDaoImpl.<init>(StuffDaoImpl.java:44)
at com.newbaz.dao.WorkDaoImpl.<init>(WorkDaoImpl.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:371)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:307)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

Please, help me. What can I do? Where is the mistake?

Regard
Dorsa

Comment: WorkDaoImpl has no parametrized Type!

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace tells you :

> nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>   at com.newbaz.dao.AbstractDao.(AbstractDao.java:19)

I don't have the line numbers but I guess it refers to :

> this.persistentClass =(Class) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];

You probably don't have that second ActualTypeArgument.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer help me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this code blows up:

```
Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Guessing generic parameters seems a pretty shaky way of detecting the type anyway. Just use the other StuffDaoImpl constructor that lets you supply the entity type and everything should work fine:

```
@Repository("workDao")
public class WorkDaoImpl extends StuffDaoImpl<Work> implements WorkDao {

    public WorkDaoImpl(){
        super(Work.class);
    }

}
```